# html table layout shrinks with body page loads

Tags: html, css, apache-tiles

i am new to designing html pages..i have searched for answer through the day.. but no luck.. i have problem in fixing my html page height fit to the browser . i am developing web page with the help of apache tiles for page layout. so in my layout i will have header , body and footer.  below is my tiles layout jsp

```
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
        <tr height="20%">
            <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="60%">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" ignore="true" />
            <td align="left">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="20%">
            <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

and i have css defined for body and table as follows

```
body {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
}

table {
table-layout: fixed;
overflow: auto;
}
```

i want to design my pages with percentage and i dont want to use pixels for scaling issues on different screen resolution.

when i load the page.. the table height shrinks with respect to the body page content size.. for e.g - if i have body page size of two line. then my footer moves up (looks weird) . i would like to fix header, body and footer with 20 % 60% and 20% respectively, and this should be fixed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's tables for you. Given them a height, and they will try to fit their content into that height for you. So with a total content 120% high, there's bound to be some conflict between what you expect and what the table produces. Solution: either let the table work out its own dimensions, or give it something non-impossible to work with.

Comment: sorry it was 20% 60% 20% and typo err..

Comment: OK, but it was two typos. After your edit, you still have 20% 80% 20% in the question.

Comment: But is your problem solved now? The height is OK now, right? I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cA6SJ/) from your code and it shows the correct height ratios of the table rows.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr Lister.. it works now.. i did miss html height param.. after adding this.. it worked ..